# Why does Blender keep freezing?

Tags: rendering, system

[image]I'm still quite new to Blender and I am trying out all kind of tutorials out there but my Blender keeps freezing the moment I go a bit into more complex projects.
I tried 2.8, 2.91, 3.0, they all behave the same.
I have Intel i7-9700k @3.60 Ghz,
Nvidia GeForce Gtx 1660 Super and 32 Gb Ram.

In Optix and Cuda the Geforce is selected. and it behaves the same in Cycles or Eevee.

But even when I am simply trying to move the view in layout without any render it is stuck.

I was trying to make a forest on a plane, all with textures and all kind of shaders (tutorial from a well known YouTube channel) but when I got into particles for my trees...it freezes.

Is there some configuration I need to do for it to work better or is my system not well equipped for this kind of work or software?

Comment: What version of blender are you using? If it's 3.0, try an earlier version. 3.0 is _supposed_ to be stable, however I've seen users complain about a myriad of issues (including odd freezing/crashing behavior) since it's official release.

Comment: Hi :). A forest can have tens of millions of vertices. You could be running into hardware limits.  You can also lower particle density for viewport previews ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am using 3.0 but I tried 2.8 and 2.91 as well...same behavior.

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that I use 1.45 Memory and Vram is at 0.7/6...where I have 32 Ram...shouldn't this be more than enough?

Comment: Blender has performance issues, especially when going a bit high in object count or poly count. Even though other softwares might be able way beyond. And tt doesn't matter if you still have available ressources in these cases.